# check if post isset for multiple click events with ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I have multiple delete buttons for some cards I have on a page, and I when I click a delete button, I want to delete the associated card's data in my database. The issue is I can't seem to figure out how to label the post for each card and check if isset([uniqueDeleteButton]), and then delete the associated meta data with that card. This is what I have so far:

javascript

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

    deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('minusInstructor');

if (deleteButtons) { 

    for(i=0; i<deleteButtons.length; i++) {

   deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

        var deleteButton = this.id
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: ajax_object.ajax_url + '?action=delete_instructors',
                data: 'minus_id=' + deleteButton,
                success:function() {
                    alert(deleteButton);
                },
                error:function() {
                    alert('failure!')
                }
            }); 



        });

    }
}
});
```

php  (plugin)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){

  wp_enqueue_script( 'Instructorsajax', plugins_url('/Instructorsajax.js', __FILE__), true);

  $localize = array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('instructor_delete') );
  wp_localize_script( 'Instructorsajax', 'ajax_object', $localize );
    
});
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_instructors', 'delete_instructors' );


function delete_instructors() {

  if (isset($_POST['minus_id']) && !empty($_POST['minus_id'])) {


    $minusID = $_POST['minus_id'];
    //each id is minusInstructor0, 1, 2, 3 etc so I'm trying to get the number only below
    $idNumber = $minusIID[15];
   

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'instructorName'.$idNumber); 
    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'instructorImg'.$idNumber);
    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'instructorDes'.$idNumber); 
    delete_post_meta($post_id, 'beltLevel'.$idNumber); 

    echo "<script>alert('deleted instructor')</script>";

    

  
  }
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

On the HTML side my delete buttons dont have names. I tried it with names but the php still couldn't identify if a post unique to each delete button is set.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!